# How to receive values from a AJAX GET call in flask restful?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, rest, flask

I am running a flask restful API, for weather prediction, flask_rest.py and a web app to consume the API named main.py. I am trying to display the output using AJAX in a HTML file named sample.html. But for some reason, the result is not displaying dynamically.
Any help is appreciated

flask_rest.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse, abort

import pandas as pd
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\jayad\Desktop\Grad\Cloud Computing\dailyweather.csv", index_col=False)
data = df.set_index('DATE').to_dict(orient='index')
data_dict = pd.DataFrame(df['DATE'])
data_dict['INDEX'] = 'DATE'
data_dict = data_dict.set_index('INDEX').to_dict(orient='records')
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('DATE', type=int)
parser.add_argument('TMAX', type=float)
parser.add_argument('TMIN', type=float)



class Historical(Resource):
    def get(self):

        return data_dict


    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        val1 = args['DATE']
        val2 = args['TMAX']
        val3 = args['TMIN']
        data[val1] = {"TMAX":val2, "TMIN":val3}
        return data[val1], 500


class Spec_historical(Resource):
    def get(self, num):

        return data[num]

    def delete(self, num):
        del data[num]
        return "DELETION DONE 300"


class forecast(Resource):
    def get(self, num):
        pred_dates={}
        date = int(num)
        pred = date - 10000
        j=date
        for i in range(7):
            if date - i in data:
                x = data.get(date - i)
                v1 = x['TMAX'] + 20
                v2 = x['TMIN'] + 20
                pred_dates[j] = {'TMAX':v1, 'TMIN':v2}

            else:
                if pred - i in data:
                    x = data.get(pred - i)
                    v1 = x['TMAX'] + 10
                    v2 = x['TMIN'] + 10
                    pred_dates[j] = {'TMAX':v1, 'TMIN': v2}
            j+=1

        return pred_dates


api.add_resource(Historical, '/Historical/')
api.add_resource(Spec_historical,'/Historical/<int:num>')
api.add_resource(forecast,'/forecast/<int:num>')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request, jsonify, Response
import requests
import simplejson as json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/forecast/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def forecast():
    error=''

    if request.method=="POST":

        a=request.form.get('given_date')

        pred_value=requests.get('http://localhost:5001/forecast/'+str(a))
        if pred_value:


            return Response(pred_value)

        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing data'})

    return render_template('sample.html', error=error)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WEATHER API</title>  
</head>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<body>
<form action="{{url_for('forecast')}}" method="POST">
    <label>DATE</label>
    <input type="text" name="given_date" id="given_date">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Enter </button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr>

      <div id="result"/>
    </form> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="text/javascritpt">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('submit').on('click',function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var $result = $('#result')
                $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    url:'/forecast/',
                    data:$('given_date')
                    dataType:'JSON'
                    success: function(result){
                         $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(result))
                    }

                }) 

             })

         })
        </script>

</body> 
</html>
```

HELP !!!

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(result);` in the `success` callback and show us the results?

Comment: can you add contentType: 'application/json', and success: function(response) to .ajax call and try ?

Comment: Tried it. Still the output dictionary is not loading in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `type:'GET'`, to `type:'POST'`.

Also, `<div>` tags require a closing tag,

so change this:

```
 <div id="result"/>
```

to this:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you are still having trouble let me know.

Comment: The problem still persists. The resulting dictionary values are not dynamically updated on the same page !

Comment: @AdhithyaJD what do you mean by "dynamically updated"?

Comment: The output values are getting displayed after the page refreshes. I want it shown right beneath the input. Sorry if my question is too basic or stupid... I am very new to the world of Ajax and jQuery. Cheers !

Comment: Did anything change?  What are your expected results, and what exactly is happening now?

Comment: No change in the output. The output dictionary is displaying after the page gets refreshed. ajax functionality is not working. I don't know what mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

First you have a mistake in your ajax call. You've forgotten a # before 'given_date':

```
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/forecast/',
            data:$('#given_date').val()
            dataType:'JSON'
            success: function(result){
                 $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(result))
            }
        })
```

If this does not solve your problem. remove the data parameter and try this one:

```
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/forecast/' + $('#given_date').val(),
            dataType:'JSON'
            success: function(result){
                 $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(result))
            }

        })
```